# setPadding on onCreateView() does not update root on Android API 16 devices after building with ProGuard

Tags: android, android-actionbar, padding, proguard

I have a fragment where on `onCreateView()` I set its root view's `paddingTop` programmatically to show it below an overlay actionbar. I simply call:

```
root.setPadding(0, 
    Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height_material)), 
    0, 0);
```

This works great on all devices I test until I build the apk with proguard. Then only on devices running API 16 (so far that I tested), the padding doesn't get updated and the root view goes under the actionbar.

I tried many changes to my proguard configuration to no avail. The latest try follows [this configuration](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377#c91) adding exceptions to all views and support libraries.

I also changed the code to add a log on my `onCreateView()` and I can see it on my console with the right padding value to be updated. It just doesn't show on the UI only for these devices on API 16.

And the fact that it works when debugging, makes finding a solution for this that much harder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDimensionPixelOffset` instead of `getDimension`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. For now what I did was to duplicate my layout resource to add the padding there. Then in code I decide which layout to inflate based on my logic. It works but it's not ideal.